# How do I make a Javascript timer where the number starts at 700000000 and counts down by 2.5 per 1 second

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I'm trying to make a timer that functions like the one on this website: http://www.gaiacoin.com/ The timer starts at 7 Billion and counts down at a rate of 2.5 points per second.

How should I write this Javascript function?

Thanks!

Comment: The first step is to learn javascript. The second - is to implement it. Looks pretty doable to me.

Comment: Show us what you have. And we will help you from there

Comment: I works now with this: 

var x = 7000000000;
setInterval(function() {
x = Math.max(0, x - 2.5);
document.getElementById("field_name").innerHTML = "Gaiacoin Clock " + x; }, 1000);


Now i'm curious about how to keep the function running after leaving the page.

Answer (score 1):

in javascript the function setInterval will call a specific function every X milliseconds based on the 2nd parameter.

```
var myNumber = 7000000000;
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
myNumber -= 2.5;
},1000);
```

the 1000 is miliseconds.. so.. 1000 miliseconds per second.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) function to create the timer, and then use [getElementById](http://getElementById) to find the spot in the HTML document to write the text.

```
var x = 7000000000;
setInterval(function() {
   x = Math.max(0, x - 2.5);
   document.getElementById("field_name").innerHTML = "Gaiacoin Clock " + x;
}, 1000);
```

**Ignore** all the down votes. Everyone that has down voted your question at some point didn't know the answer either, and how do we learn unless we ask for help.

Comment: How would I keep that function running after leaving the page?

Comment: You'd could make the start time relative to the current time, but since I don't know what 7 billion stands for I can't advise.

Comment: the function can not run if it's not in the page

Comment: Would I use a server language like php to run the clock?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it

```
var startValue = 7000000000;

// arbitrarily started at midnight 7th November 2015 UTC
// change to whatever you want, 
// or even read something from a cookie if you want
var startTime = new Date(2015, 10, 7, 0, 0, 0); 

var perSec = 2.5;

var beginOffset = new Date() - startTime;
var startPerform = performance.now();
var displayValue;

var go = function() {
    var elapsed = beginOffset + (performance.now() - startPerform);
    var value = Math.floor(startValue - perSec * elapsed / 1000);
    if(value != displayValue) {
        console.log(displayValue = value); // do your output here
    }
}
setInterval(go, 100);
```